# Use same variable individually in two GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

What I have right now are two boxes been moved by the same `script`, it happens if the `boolean` `canMove`, which is in the script, is `true`.

The problem I have is that I want to turn `canMove` to false for just one of those `GameObjects`. But when I do that, obviously, it changes for both `GameObjects`.

What could I do to have control on this variable on each `GameObject`?

Comment: Hi. Can you post the part of the code that contains the boolean?

Comment: is the script attached to each gameobject ?

Comment: @Reasurria Hi, I don’t have the script right now, but it’s just a private bool canMove with an OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit that make the Boolean false and true, in that order.

Comment: @Xamassassin Yes, is just one script attached to both GameObjects.

Comment: Please don't add `[Solved]` to the title. The question will already visibly marked as solved once an answer is marked as accepted.

Comment: @derHugo ohh, ok! I’m new here! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct the issue is you have a script lets say like

```
public class CollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool CanMove;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        CanMove = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        CanMove = true;
    }
}
```

and you want to set it to `false` only to one of the objects, right?

Maybe a bit hacky but you could do

```
public static List<GameObject> lastReset;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //get your own index in list
    var myIndex = lastReset.IndexOf(gameObject);

    //get others index
    var otherIndex = lastReset.IndexOf(other.gameObject);

    // Only go on if other is exactly the object in front of you
    if(otherIndex != myIndex - 1) return;

    // You way to define if can move
    CanMove = ...;
}
```

Than wherever you do your resetting also do

```
CollisionHandler.lastReset.Remove(objectYouReset);
CollisionHandler.lastReset.Add(objectYouReset);
```

To remove it and set it to the end of the list.

Comment: That’s what I want, but I didn’t mention something I thought wasn’t relevant, but now I see it is. I want one of the objects to set canMove when it collides with the other object that has the same script. What I was trying is to use collider.bounds to say that when the OnTriggerEnter is called, if the bounds.max of the box A is less than bounds.min of box B box B stop moving so the two objects don’t overlap. The problem is that the script is deactivating both GameObjects movement.

Comment: But for which object do you want to deactivate it? And you can do the same for `OnTriggerEnter`. And you can add whatever check you want in order to "filter" some condition

Comment: Let me explain you, these two boxes are moving one behind the other, and there is a 3rd game object that when collides with each box send them back to the starting point, creating a loop. The problem is that one of the boxes is bigger than the other, so when these are sent away, they are overlapping, and that’s what I don’t want. So, having that in mind, it is not defined which of the boxes is going to deactivate the other, all We know is that one of those is going to deactivate the other.

Comment: Isn't the one that should be stopped allways the one that was reset last?

Comment: in this case, it is, but I want it more generic because I’ll add more boxes later so the first deactivates the second, the second the third and it goes on...

Comment: See my update .. you now only make the object stop if it collides with the one in front of it.

Comment: oh dude, thanks I cannot try it right now, but I’m pretty sure it’s going to work! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make bool variable public so that you can see them in inspector.
Now change the **true** for one and **false** for other in Inspector.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I want the Boolean to change depending on wether it is colliding with an specific object or not.